# javascript (html5) -Can I disable two keys from firing at the same time, simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, button, key

I am making a game. I want to enable firing from either left mouse button or space on a keyboard. 
But...

I don't want to allow double firing. By fast pressing both space and left mouse, I get double power. I played some desktop games, where firing is the same, regardless of pressing both keys or just one.

Edit:
When I press both space and left mouse, code gets double executed. 
Ok, it could be that it is not double executed, it could be that I am firing really fast when using both buttons, but I don't understand how some desktop games, for example chicken invaders implemented it so it fires always the same amount of projectiles, either pressing space or mouse or both mouse and space. even when you are firing really fast.

Comment: Just remember if you're already firing because of the one kind of event, and if so disregard the other. What's the issue exactly?

Comment: please share some of your code. What you've got so far?

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Without your code, we can only guess

Comment: But why do you need a code. It is a simple thing. When pressing mouse left, fire weapon. When pressing space on a keyboard, do the same. It works without any problems. Problem appears when pressing both mouse and a space, and it is not a bug of any kind, it just double fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle both keys with an AND

```
if(keyPressed["<key1>"] && keyPressed["<key2>"]) {
//Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did something similar. onkeyup and onmouseup i set two variables to false (spacepress and mousepress). (Not both, mousepress only on mouseup and spacepress only on keyup). And onkeydown and mousedown setting those variables to to true, and then did some checking. Returned from event if both are true.